Reverse SSH port forwarding doesn't work if an unrelated loopback interface is down
I have a remote machine which usually has 2 loopback interfaces:
root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo

lo100: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet 127.0.0.2 netmask 0xffff0000
        inet6 fe80::1%lo100 prefixlen 64 tentative scopeid 0x5
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo

From this machine, I open a reverse ssh to a well known host as. Say it starts listening on port 12345.
ssh -N \
    -T \
    -R 0:127.0.0.1:22 \
    remote@remotemachine.com

From the remotemachine.com, when I login, I do the following. This works fine.
ssh -p 12345 root@127.0.0.1

Here's the problem:

if I do ifconfig lo100 down, then the SSH from the remotemachine.com no longer works until I do a ifconfig lo100 up.
instead, if I do ifconfig lo100 down destroy and the restart the remote SSH command, then things work fine.

Why is reverse ssh command dependent on lo100 being up when lo0 is the one holding onto 127.0.0.1 (which is the IP used in the reverse SSH command)?

The issue is with the netmask that was set on lo100.

By default, lo100 seems to have netmask as 255.255.0.0 (i.e. /16). This is somehow conflicting with lo0 and causing issues when the reverse connection is set up.
The issue is described in detail below.

On the VM, we see the following interfaces:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig lo100
lo100: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet 127.0.0.2 netmask 0xffff0000
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo
root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig lo0
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo


After starting reverse SSH on the VM, we can login from the jump:

# remote @ remotemachine.com in ~ [14:22:36]
$ ssh -p 60454 ...
Last login: Fri Dec 20 06:19:57 2024 from 127.0.0.1
...


After logging in from the jump, we see the following sockets open:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > sockstat -c -P tcp | grep ssh
root     sshd       88301 4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:22          127.0.0.2:56760         <<<< lo100 IP
root     sshd       88065 4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:22          127.0.0.2:56760
...


If we bring down lo100, then the ssh from the jump stops:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig lo100 down
root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > sockstat -c -P tcp | grep ssh
root     ssh        74726 4  tcp4   127.0.0.2:56760       127.0.0.1:22


from the jump, we are unable to ssh back again.

# remote @ remotemachine.com in ~ [14:26:26]
$ ssh -p 60454 ...
^C%

# remote @ remotemachine.com in ~ [14:26:26]
$

If we set netmask on lo100 to 255.0.0.0 (i.e. /8), then it does not conflict to lo0.
This means irrespective of what happens to lo100 (down and/or destroy), the reverse SSH connection doesn't get reset.
Proof of working below.

On the VM, we see the following interfaces:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig lo100
lo100: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet 127.0.0.2 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo
root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > ifconfig lo0
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: lo


After starting reverse SSH on the VM, we can login from the jump:

# remote @ remotemachine.com in ~ [14:30:02]
$ ssh -p 62768 ...
Last login: Fri Dec 20 06:29:35 2024 from 127.0.0.2
...


After logging in from the jump, we see the following sockets open:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : / > sockstat -c -P tcp | grep ssh
zsroot   sshd       35528 4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:22          127.0.0.1:60722           <<< lo0 IP
...


If we bring down lo100, then the ssh from the jump does not stop:

root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : zsroot > ifconfig lo100 down
root@ip-10-1-250-4.us-west-2.compute.internal : zsroot > sockstat -c -P tcp | grep ssh
root     sshd       35528 4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:22          127.0.0.1:60722
root     sshd       35304 4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:22          127.0.0.1:60722
...

